# is it possible high CPU consumption with getEntryAfterMiss(ThreadLocal.java:444)

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, logback

We observed 100% CPU utilization on our production server that resulted very slow performance.In thread dump we saw most of threads were RUNNABLE with below stacktrace:

```
   at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.getEntryAfterMiss(ThreadLocal.java:444)
   at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.getEntry(ThreadLocal.java:419)
   at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$000(ThreadLocal.java:298)
   at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:163)
   at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.LogbackMDCAdapter.remove(LogbackMDCAdapter.java:122)
   at org.slf4j.MDC.remove(MDC.java:224)
```

May this cause the 100% CPU Utilization?

Comment: No, it cannot. Chck which threads are using a lot of CPU using the HTOP utility. Then take a thread dump and check what these threads are doing.